# Sorting by date with a DB in Django

Tags: python, django

I have the following model.py.

```
from django.db import models

class Address(models.Model):
    addr = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.addr)

class Anniversary(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.date)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birthday = models.DateField()
    anniversary = models.ForeignKey(Anniversary)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s %s' % (self.name, self.birthday, self.anniversary, self.address)
```

I want to print the contents of all entries into my template. But sorted by date of birth against the current date. i.e most recent first and then name. What is the best way to do this. Should I sort it first and then append it to a list or dict ?

Any pointers would be great.

Thanks,

Comment: What's wrong with `order_by`?

Comment: If your Address and Anniversary models are as simple as this then it would be much better to move those fields into your Person model instead.

Comment: The documentation is pretty thorough in this regard... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by

Answer (score 13):

You can add default ordering in a model's meta class, e.g.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    # fields
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('anniversary__date',)
```

then in your template it's as easy as:

```
<ul>
    {% for person in persons %}
        <li>{{ person.anniversary.date|date:"M d, Y" }} - {{ person.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

If you need custom ordering within a view (to filter out persons based on the request object):

```
def myview(request):
    context = dict(
        persons = Person.objects.exclude(person.id=request.user.id)\
                                .order_by('anniversary__date')
    )
    return render_to_response('app/template.html', context)
```

N.b. Adding a minus before your order_by parameter `order_by('-attr')` reverses ordering.

As @DanielEriksson mentioned, if your case isn't hypothetic, it seems you should simplify things.

Comment: Thanks, the odd thing is even if I assign the objects.all() to persons. And then iterate over it nothing is displayed within the template (??)

Comment: @felix001 add your views.py

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this :

```
          persons = Person.objects.all().order_by(birthday ,anniversary)
```

In you view you can get the current date using :

```
          import datetime 
          now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

and then :

```
          persons = Person.objects.all().order_by(now, anniversary)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks but it sorts the date for the birthday but not against the current date (??)

Comment: Thanks but that also doesnt seem to work to well. If I add (now, anniversy) then I get an error saying that the variables havent been assigned, but if I just use ... ('now', 'birthday') then I get the error ---------------->

Caught FieldError while rendering: Cannot resolve keyword 'now' into field. Choices are: address, anniversary, birthday, id, name

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to avoid sorting in the Model, since it's more a presentation/view type thing. I tend to use sorted in render_to_response for single value sorting, or order_by for multi-value sorting. Using sorted in the return statement lets me kind of split the difference between the view/template, since Django views aren't entirely controllers. Anyway, this is just my preference. You can also use [dictsort](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#dictsort) in the template to do single value sorting.

You have indicated you want to sort using multiple values, first by most recent birth date and second by the name. To do this, I would use order_by in a view, then comment my return statement:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def view_persons(request):

    persons = Person.objects.all().order_by('-birthday', 'name')

    return render_to_response(
        'view_persons.html',
        {
            'persons': persons,  # ordered by most recent birthday, then name
        },
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

In the template, you have little more to do than:

```
{% if persons %}
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Birthday</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
  {% for person in persons %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ person.birthday }}</td>
        <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
      </tr>
  {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
{% else %}
  <p>There are no people!</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the complexity is that you need to compare the sorted date against the current date, not simply sorted by date.

If you are using Postgres and are happy to stick to raw SQL, you could potentially use their datetime functions, such as age

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html

Otherwise, you would need to select where the date of birth/anniversary is greater than now. It might be simpler if you refactored your anniversary model to store the day, month and year a separate fields, so that you can ignore the year when filtering.

I recently posted some code in a question, that might give you some hints - I need to return events closest to now. See:

[Is it bad practice to return a tuple from a Django Manager method rather than a queryset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246195/is-it-bad-practice-to-return-a-tuple-from-a-django-manager-method-rather-than-a)