# Is it bad practice to return a tuple from a Django Manager method rather than a queryset?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have some complex business logic that I have placed in a custom ModelManager. The manager method returns a tuple of values rather than a queryset. Is this considered bad practice? if so, what is the recommended approach. I do not want the logic in the View, and Django has no Service tier. Plus, my logic needs to potentially perform multiple queries.

The logic needs to select an Event closest to the current time, plus 3 events either side. When placed in the template, it is helpful to know the closest event as this is the event initially displayed in a full-screen slider.

The current call is as follows:

```
closest_event, previous_events, next_events = Event.objects.closest()
```

The logic does currently work fine. I am about to convert my app. to render the Event data as JSON in the template so that I can bootstrap a backbone.js View on page load. I plan to use TastyPie to render a Resource server-side into the template. Before I refactor my code, it would be good to know my current approach is not considered bad practice.

This is how my app. currently works:

views.py

```
class ClosestEventsListView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'events/event_list.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        closest_event, previous_events, next_events = Event.objects.closest()

        context['closest_event'] = closest_event
        context['previous_events'] = previous_events
        context['next_events'] = next_events
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

models.py

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

from model_utils.models import TimeStampedModel

class ClosestEventsManager(models.Manager):
    def closest(self, **kwargs):
        """
        We are looking for the closest event to now plus the 3 events either side.
        First select by date range until we have a count of 7 or greater
        Initial range is 1 day eithee side, then widening by another day, if required
        Then compare delta for each event data and determine the closest
        Return closest event plus events either side
        """
        now = timezone.now()
        range_in_days = 1
        size = 0

        while size < 7:
            start_time = now + timedelta(days=-range_in_days)
            end_time = now + timedelta(days=range_in_days)
            events = self.filter(date__gte=start_time, date__lte=end_time, **kwargs).select_related()
            size = events.count()
            range_in_days += 1

        previous_delta = None
        closest_event = None
        previous_events = None
        next_events = None
        position = 0

        for event in events:
            delta = (event.date - now).total_seconds()
            delta = delta * -1 if delta < 0 else delta
            if previous_delta and previous_delta <= delta:
                # we have found the closest event. Now, based on
                # position get events either size
                next_events = events[:position-1]
                previous_events = events[position:]
                break

            previous_delta = delta
            closest_event = event
            position += 1

        return closest_event, previous_events, next_events


class Event(TimeStampedModel):

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']

    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    event_type = models.ForeignKey(EventType)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    end_time = models.TimeField()
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    twitter_hashtag = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
    web_link = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)

    objects = ClosestEventsManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's bad practice to return a tuple. The first example in the [ModelManager docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods) returns a list.

Saying that, if you want to build a queryset instead then you could do something like this -

```
def closest(self, **kwargs):
    # get the events you want
    return self.filter(pk__in=([event.id for event in events]))
```

Comment: Interesting. I would never have thought of doing that. In my case, I'd need to also order_by date again. I have since altered my code to return a merged list, but returning a queryset would be preferable.

Answer (score 2):

It's fine, even Django's own `get_or_create` does it. Just make sure it's clear to whoever's using the function that it's not chainable (ie doesn't return a queryset).

Comment: Good spot. Well, that's pretty definitive then. Going with Aidan's answer simply because it offered an option I hadn't thought of.